# Qt c++ how to input values

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, input

I'm working on Visual studio (c++) and I'm using Qt along with OpenCV.
What I want to do is create a window where I can input several values that will be used in an algorithme later. These variables are double and int type.
I've looked at the Qt doc and on the internet but I didn't find a proper way to do so. I'm also not looking for a dialog box to pop up and ask the user to input values, just a window with several fields to type my values and update them. 
Any help would be appreciated, thanks

EDIT:
I'm now using a QDoubleSpinBox to input a double value and a button to update and print the value in a console.
I've created a class for my button to be able to use custom SLOTS in main.h :

```
class MyButton : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyButton();

public slots:
    void updateValue(QDoubleSpinBox* input);
};
```

And this is the main.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"

#include <QtGui>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double value;

MyButton::MyButton() : QWidget()
{
    QPushButton *update = new QPushButton("update",this);
    connect(update, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(updateValue(QDoubleSpinBox)));
}

void MyButton::updateValue(QDoubleSpinBox *input)
{
    input->update();
    value = input->value(); 
    cout<<value;
}
```

Now I'm not sure what to write in the 'main' function to use that to create the button. Here is my 'main' function so far:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget window;

    QDoubleSpinBox *input = new QDoubleSpinBox();
    input->setValue(5.00);

    QVBoxLayout *vbox1 = new QVBoxLayout;
    vbox1->addWidget(input);

    window.setLayout(vbox1);
    window.resize(800,600);
    window.show();
    window.setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("toplevel", "Top-level widget"));
    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your task you should know the following topics:
1. which **widgets** can be used **to get input from a user**(most of them were already stated);
2. **SIGNALS & SLOTS** in Qt (using them you can assign values which were provided to a widget to your variables).

As that topics are rather volumable I advice you to refer to **Qt documentation** (use **Qt assistant** for example), as now you know for what information to search it will be easier for you to solve you task

Comment: Thank you, I'm using a QDoubleSpinBox to get double values and a button to update the value.  
Quick question though, is it possible to create a custom SLOT (that will call a custom function for updating and displaying the value in the console) without creating a class?

Comment: SLOT should always be "binded" to class, otherwise it is not usefull. Class should contain macro Q_OBJECT and inherit from class which provides SIGNALS & SLOT functionality (for ex. QOBject, or QtWidget).

Comment: Ok, I've created a class but I'm not sure how to use it. I've followed a tuto (in french) but I don't know how to use it in the 'main' function. I'll edit my first post

Comment: Qt documentation contains a lot of examples, they are arranged in groups for users convenience. I advice you to refer to "Qt Examples and Demos package" which is provided with Qt, and look for ex. in group "dialogs". In that group is shown on practice how to get input from user and porcess it. When I have faced with Qt for the first time using Qt examples made allowed me to learn it faster and with pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

There are several input widgets in Qt. For example QLineEdit, QSpinBox and QDoubleSpinBox. You can create several of them and put them in a grid layout.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that. 
There are so many classes, it's hard to know what to look for if you don't know the names of the classes.

Comment: @alvinleetya The link UmNyobe posted above should be helpful (after you click on one of the styles.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess QLineEdit is what you are looking for. However, you will need to type check yourself, if that is what you are after.

And indeed, it is not easy to find. My last Qt implementation was a while ago, and it took me a little time to find it in the Qt docs.

Comment: In Qt it is done automaticly by QValidator. e.g myLineEdit->setValidator( new QDoubleValidator );

Answer (score 0):

Curious you couldn't find... Try [QInputDialog](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qinputdialog.html) and see if it works for you, otherwise subclass [QDialog](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qdialog.html) and create the dialog as you prefer.

Comment: But I do not want it to be a dialog box :p